# Denormalizing on server-side vs. reducing on client-side

Tags: meteor, reactjs, meteor-react

I'm new to Meteor and followed through the React tutorial, which mostly made sense.

What are guidelines for using denormalizers? The incompleteCount denormalizer in the tutorial seems like it could be easily done on the client side, i.e. just running a reduce on the todos. What are the considerations that caused it to be made into a denormalizer? Is it just when you want the computed value outside of the component that computes it?

I'm running into similar circumstances in my own project. So far I've just been computing on the client side, and seems to be working, but would like to be future-proof!

Thanks!